# Flex: How to scale the results of using ImageSnapshot.captureImage on a canvas

Tags: canvas, flex4

I'm using `ImageSnapshot.captureImage(canvas, 0, jPEGEncoder)` to capture a drawing canvas to a bitmap, but I'd like the resulting jpeg much larger than the canvas itself.

For example, the canvas is 100x400 but I want the resulting image of the canvas to be 200x800.  I can't enlarge/scale the canvas up to this size because it'll mess up the UI.

Answer (score 0):

scaleLimited:Boolean (default = true) — `The maximum width or height of a bitmap in Flash is 2880 pixels` - if scaleLimited is set to true the resolution will be reduced proportionately to fit within 2880 pixels, otherwise, if scaleLimited is false, smaller snapshot windows will be taken and stitched together to capture a larger image. The default is true.

[Info Site](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/graphics/ImageSnapshot.html#captureImage%28%29)

Comment: the question isn't about the max size, but how to scale an image captured using ImageSnapshot.captureImage.

Comment: Could you take some of your code here ?Sometimes if you try to change some view as you want,you should take care the way you use.
I mean:How did you take a look on this method using? By Click Button and not Bindable data? or put it in an itemrenderer then didn't call it re work? Plz take some code here more better.
Another word,in my memory your post "200x800" is 2000x8000 before you edited it,so i try to guess the reason and post.